# I cannot grant WRITE_SETTING permissions in android with api 23

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I tried to grant WRITE_SETTING permissions to allow my application to increase the brightness in a view I tried the code below as it is mentioned in the documentation of android but every time no popup that allows the user to accept or deny the permission I tried to debug the code grantResults [0] is always equal to -1

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS),
                    10
                )

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            Settings.System.putInt(
                this.contentResolver,
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 255
            )
        }


    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            10 -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                    Settings.System.putInt(
                        this.contentResolver,
                        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,255
                    )
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return
            }

            // Add other 'when' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
            else -> {
                // Ignore all other requests.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WRITE_SETTINGS` is not one that you can request via `requestPermissions()`. That is only for `dangerous` permissions, and `WRITE_SETTINGS` does not have that `protectionLevel`.

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS):

> Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS`. The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling `Settings.System.canWrite()`.